# Automatically Parameterizing Steps in QTP

Tags: qtp

What is the use for Automatically Parameterizing step using Test Parameters?

Answer (score 1):

While this option is selected, QTP replaces the **constant values** of your steps with **action parameters**.

#### Option disabled

Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebEdit("q").Set **"hello world"**

#### Option enabled

Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebEdit("q").Set **Parameter("q_Text")** 'q_Text defaults to "hello world"

Note: ***File -> Settings -> Parameters*** displays all automatically created parameters such as "q_Text" and you can provide different values when you Press F5 to playback your test.